# Capturing webpage with frames using WebKit

Tags: image, macos, webkit, frame, capture

I am developing an OSX application in which I create an CIImage from web-view loaded. Following is the code snippet to do that:

```
NSView *docView = [[[webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView];
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [docView  bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect: [docView frame]];
[docView cacheDisplayInRect: [docView frame] toBitmapImageRep:imageRep];
CIImage *webPageImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithBitmapImageRep: imageRep];
```

But, using this code I am not able to capture the webpage that has frames. Following web page has frames: http://api.rubyonrails.org

How do I solve this problem?